# Round all values in top row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been searching for a solution to my problem but it seems that all solutions are for columns.  I'm trying to change a row.

My data frame looks like this:
[image]

How can I round all the values in the top row only?

I tried:

```
new = df.iloc[0].round()
df.update(new)
```

But this took the top row rounded values and replaced the first column instead of the top row.

I'm reading my data in like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
```

Comment: `df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].round()`?

Comment: Yeah.  That's it. Thanks!

Comment: `df.iloc[0].round()` returns a Series where the name is 0. So when you `update` The DataFrame it thinks this should update the Series in the DataFrame (i.e. the column) labeled `0`. IF you need to use `update` then you'd want to make sure you grabbed the DataFrame row with `df.iloc[[0]].round()`